# Wordpress 3.8.3 custom theme

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, slider, themes

I'm building custom WP theme and I have issues with sliders. None of those I've tried to install worked.
When I looked into the developers console, and searched for their js/css files, they where not there.
Not in the header or the footer.
One of those plugins had option to include his files into header or footer - tried to change that but didn't work.
Contact form and pagenavi are working just fine, but sliders not.
There are no js errors, because there are no files to cause them.
WP version is 3.8.3. jQuery 1.9.3 is included and working fine.
Am I missing something in my functions.php ( theme is made from scratch ) maybe?

Comment: I think you should ask this on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: moved there, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see more of your code for a proper answer. But just wondering if you have the correct wp action hooks in your header and footer?

In the **header.php** right before the `</head>` this should be there: **`<?php wp_head(); ?>`**

In the **footer.php** right before the `</body>` this should be there: **`<?php wp_footer(); ?>`**

Make sure you have those.

Comment: That did the trick.I tried that last night ( one guy from other forum reminded me about wp_heah/wp_footer ), and it worked. I was working with WP 12h in a row, must have slipped that out.
Thank you anyway.